# Cloning system to new SSD - adjusting partition layout

Tags: boot, partitioning, gpt

I want to clone my current Windows installation to a new, larger SSD. My current system drive had 3 partitions: 16 MB microsoft reserved, OS itself (C:) and recovery.
However, due to my previous partitions moving attempt ESD/EFI partition in on another (HDD) drive. Also, my new SSD is 2x bigger than current one. So it would be nice to make some adjustments.

I read that GUID/GPT partitioning scheme and EDI boot don't rely as much on block numbers as MBR. Is it possible to place EFI/ESD partition before C: and moving repair partition at the end of new drive in a way, that doesn't hurt Windows installation and after removing old system drive Windows boot from new drive and work correctly?

Comment: An SSD has no beginning and no end - just places in memory. Your goal cannot be logically achieved.

Comment: But the cells could be anywhere in memory. There is no like organization to a hard drive.

Comment: Just copy the partitions to their new place, and once the new disk boots use Disk Management to resize the C: partition.